# Noughts and Crosses loops

Tags: for-loop, python-3.x, nested-loops, nested-lists

iv'e been working on this question, and i think im nearly there.

Question:

Write a function get_column(game, col_num) that takes a legal 3 x 3 game of noughts and crosses and returns a 3-element list containing the values from column number col_num, top to bottom. You may assume col_num is in the range 0 to 2 inclusive. [Hint: you will have to build the return value by looping over the rows, picking out the required element of each row.]

My working:

```
def get_column(game, col_num):
    x = []
    for i in game:
        for j in i:
            x.append(i[col_num])
    return x
```

Testing:

column1 = get_column([['O', 'X', 'O'], ['X', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ']], 0)

print(column1)

Results:

['O', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ']

Wanted format:

['O', 'X', ' '].

I'm pretty sure i'm getting the correct answer, however, not in the right format. the results are showing that im increasing the 'O'/'X' two more time. i guess this has something to do with the loops, but i can detect what exactly.

any help would be appreciated! Cheers!

Comment: What is your actual question. You need to phrase more explicitly what you want help with. Simply "Any help would be appreciated" isn't much of a question, so I don't know what to say to help you.

Comment: I've compared the "Results" of running the code with the "wanted format" at the end. I'm in my early stages of programming, so im still learning how to express code issues, especially over here. so sorry for that. nonetheless, the others have pointed out the bug and its all sorted. but thanks for dropping by Alex :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_column(game, col_num):
    x = []
    for i in range(3):
        x.append(game[i][col_num])
    return x
```

Comment: The code returns to me:TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list. Error in line 4.
However, Jon Kiparsky helped me out and its running.
But much thanks Andrew!:)

Comment: my bad, change in game to in range(3)

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in game:
        for j in i:
            x.append(i[col_num])
```

I'm assuming that game is a list of lists of three. In this case, your inner loop iterates over each of the three items in i, and appends i[col_num] once for each of them. 
Omit the inner loop (for j in i) and it should work correctly.